# How to get 85% max all resist?

Tags: path-of-exile

I saw a video from Kripparrian where he has a build with 85% max all resist.
But I can't find any real ways of increasing my max resists.
Barbarism only increases max fire resist by 1% and potions only increase max resist temporarily.

Is this something that has been changed recently?

Edit:
[Purity of elements](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Resistances) gives no extra max resist
On the [resistances](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Resistances) page says indeed that there are ways to increase max resistances.
But there's no real way of increasing them to a permanent 85% percent, they all have problems:

- [Saffell's Frame](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Saffell%27s_Frame) Increase all max resist by 4%, but does not block normal attacks
- [Divination Distillate](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Divination_Distillate) Increases all max resist by 6%, but only for 5 seconds
- The aura's each only increase max resist of one type by 5%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the information is there on the wiki. You can get 4% from Saffell, and up to 8.X% from each purity aura if you invest in nodes that buff aura effects, and you can run all three auras if your build is setup for it. That's if you want to get >85% permanently *today*.

I don't know how recent whatever video you're looking at, but afaik Kripp only really played in beta. Looking at the history of skills and items, note that:

- [Saffell's Flame](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Saffell's_Frame#Legacy_variants) used to give 5% max resists (<1.1) compared to 4%
- [Purity of Elements](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Purity_of_Elements#Version_history) used to give 5% max resists (<1.0.1) compared to 0%, and all 3 Purity of X didn't exist until this was nerfed.

So I suppose he would have had to invest less in the tree to reach 85% than you would have now.

Comment: He probably used Saffell's Flame and Purity of Elements, which no longer increases max resist. Thanks.

Comment: Max resists are nerfed even further in awakening since there is no inner force cluster anymore. This means auras cant buff as much as they used too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shield that raises max ele resist, and the purity gems can as well.  I'm sure taking a look through the wiki may also provide further answers under the section containing elemental resist information.